# How much did Owen and Beru know?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars

Through the first 8 Star Wars episodes, we only see two sets of scenes with Uncle Owen and Aunt Beru.

In A New Hope, Owen tries to dissuade Luke from consorting with Old Ben.  We get a sense that he at least knows Ben's true nature.  No other reference to Luke's relationship to Anakin is explicitly referenced in this film.

In Revenge of the Sith, we see baby Luke get adopted by Owen and Beru.  But it is unclear how much they are told.

My question is, did Owen and Beru know that Luke was the progeny of Anakin?

As pointed out, these very well could be relatives of Anakin (although I wonder if Aunt and Uncle are token titles)

I am really wondering whether they know Luke is *Vader's* son.

Comment: Beru certainly says "There's too much of his father in him", to which Owen says "That's what I'm afraid of". So it would seem they know it's Anakin (or that they know his father in general). What is still unclear is how much they really know about Anakin's fate.

Comment: There might be a bit more in the Star Wars comic, as Obi-Wan has a bit of an arc chronicling a flashback were he found himself at odds with Owen, while watching over Luke and of course the Obi-Wan miniseries is coming out next year for Disney+ and that could shed more light on this!

Comment: _"We get a sense that he at least knows Ben's true nature"._ Your reason for assuming so isn't definitive. For example, if Owen had seen this "stranger" observing them for decades, that's perfectly reasonable for Owen to not like Ben. _We_ know that Ben would just be keeping Luke safe and checking in, but that doesn't inherently prove that Owen is made aware of  that.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156583/do-aunt-beru-and-uncle-owen-know-that-anakin-skywalker-is-darth-vader

Comment: Why would they take a baby from a stranger? They must've known that it is the grandson of their step-mother

Comment: I suppose then, TK, that this should have been reworded.  I wanted to know whether they were raising *Vader's* son.

Comment: Technically they are relatives to Anakin. Owen’s father married Anakin’s mother when he bought and freed her, making Anakin a stepbrother to Owen. Not blood relatives but legal relatives.

Comment: It always seemed to me that with the original movie standing by itself (back in 1977), Luke's father Annikin and Vader were two separate individuals; in that context, Beru's line is mostly a throw-away. In this sense, Empire Strikes Back retconned Annikin and Vader into the same person, making Obi-Wan's statement about Vader killing Annikin somewhat problematic. Had Obi-Wan said "Vader *destroyed* your father" (rather than "killed"), it would have made more narrative sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Napaloen Wislon mentioned in the comments, *A New Hope's* dialogue does suggest they knew something about who Luke's father is.

> Beru: There's too much of his father in him.
>
> Owen: That's what I'm afraid of.

In addition the 2015 [Star Wars Comic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015_comic_book)) that takes place between *A New Hope* and *The Empire Strikes Back* includes one arc that features Obi-Wan's journals and flashes back to tell a specific tale.

During these events, Obi-Wan ends up getting involved with a young Luke Skywalker, leading to a situation where Owen confronts Obi-Wan, saying that he will not let The Jedi 'warp the boy, like he  did his father.' It's taken even a step further when Owen also says,

> "Haven't you murdered enough **Skywalkers** already, Kenobi?"

[image: comic 2]

[image: comic 1]

Readers can see from these passages/panles that Owen did seem to know a bit about the Jedi, that Luke's father was a "dead" Skywalker, and that Obi-wan played a role in what happened to Luke's father. If we take these lines and couple them with *A New Hope's* breif dialogue, it seems pretty apparent that Owen knew that Anakin Skywalker became Darth Vader.

---

<sub>This also may get elaborated on even further, as there is an upcoming [Obi-Wan](https://www.slashgear.com/star-wars-obi-wan-kenobi-mini-series-tipped-for-disney-streaming-service-20566614/) miniseries in the works for Disney+ that also takes place while Obi-Wan is exhiled on Tatooine. It's filming this summer and likely won't air until 2021.</sub>

Comment: 1) LOOKING FORWARD to that Obi-Wan series!!!!! and 2) I need to start reading the comic series. They have interesting info from outside the films/series.